# Alter Stage to convert it into external stage (Read from S3) Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created stage with json format to copy data from desktop to snowflake. Now I want to load data from s3 bucket instead of desktop.

```
alter stage investor_stage set url='s3://em_pi'
```

IF I need to create a  new stage with s3 url I am able to create, but unable to alter  the exsisting one

Error : SQL compilation error: Cannot set URL, credentials, or encryption key of an internal or temporary stage.

Thanks,
xi

Answer (score 2):

When you created the stage the first time, you likely didn't specify any parameters that force the stage to be created as an `EXTERNAL` stage, which means it's an `INTERNAL` stage.  You can not alter a stage to make that stage be `EXTERNAL` once its already `INTERNAL`.  So, you can't add URL, credentials, or encryption key on an `INTERNAL` stage, because those never have one.

So, you need to create a new stage that has a URL, which makes it `EXTERNAL`.

Take a look at the documentation here on what parameters make a stage `INTERNAL` vs. `EXTERNAL` as they are very different things.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html#syntax